# Getting all guilds the bot is in and banning the member in all discords

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pycord

So I am trying to get all guilds that the bot is in. Which I have done by:

```
for guild in self.bot.guilds:
  guild = guild
```

Using this I need to try and ban the member specified in all of the guilds that the bot is in.
Can anyone help with this?

I have already tried by looping the code to ban the user in all of the servers but seems to not ban them with no error in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that this is being called in an `async` function and you have gotten the `USER_ID` of the user you want to ban. You have the `pycord` label as well - so linked those docs.

```py
user_id = USER_ID  # the ID of the 'specified' member you want to ban
async for guild in self.bot.fetch_guilds():
    # could also use guild.get_member(user_id) if you Intents.members enabled and member cache
    try:
        member = await guild.fetch_member(user_id)
    except discord.NotFound:
        # user wasn't in this guild
        # move to next guild
        continue
    await member.ban()
```

Using [`fetch_guilds`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/clients.html#discord.Bot.fetch_guilds) in case you don't have them in the cache. And [`fetch_member`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/models.html#discord.Guild.fetch_member) in case they're not cached either - but you can use [`get_member`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/models.html#discord.Guild.get_member) instead if you have `Intents.members` enabled and member caching enabled.

[`member.ban`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/models.html#discord.Member.ban) docs.